# write an expression for the nth term of the sequence....

Tags: algebra-precalculus

write an expression for the nth term of the sequence 0, 7, 16, 27, 40 
It is neither geometric or arithmetic

My teacher gave us a key and I can't read his writing...please any help would be great!!

Comment: Can you ask your teacher for a more legible key?

Comment: I've emailed him many times after school and he never checks his emails till the next day... Not sure if it's worth it!

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Check the differences between consecutive terms, they are in AP.

Next time show your attempts, else you might not get any help here.

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure what equation to use... is it a(n)=a1+(n-1)xd? so I would use 2 for d because the difference between the consecutive terms have a difference of two?

Comment: Not the difference of consecutive terms, but the difference of consecutive _differences_, so you cannot simply use the arithmetic sequence formula on $a_n$ .  (If the difference between terms _were_ constant, then you _would_ have an arithmetic sequence.)  Instead, you have $a_2 - a_1 \ = \ d_1 \ = \ 7 \ $ , $a_3 - a_2 \ = \ d_2 \ = d_1 + 2 \ = \ 9 \ $ , $a_4 - a_3 \ = \ d_3 + 2 \cdot 2 \ = \ 11 \ $ , etc.  The $d_n$'s have an arithmetic formula; how can you use that to make a formula (which is _not_ arithmetic) for the $a_n$'s ?

Answer (score 2):

Just a few thoughts that might (might not) be helpful:

$$\begin{align}
0&\\
7 &= 0 + 7 + 0\cdot 2\\
16 &= 7 + 7 + 1\cdot 2\\
27 &= 16 + 7 + 2\cdot 2\\
40 &= 27 + 7 + 3\cdot 2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: is the equation set up for this a(n)=a1+(n-1)xd? so  then I use the difference of the consecutive terms (2) as d? I'm just confused how to set up the equation I need to write. SO i have the first term and the common difference, do I need to now plug a term in to get out something else? I'm sorry i've very lost.

Comment: @user76537: So $a_1 =0$, $a_2 = 7$ and so on. Can you, from the above figure out what $a_6$ is? What is $a_7$. Write down some more terms. Then try to figure out a formula that holds for all these.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sequence defined by (n+6)n:

(0+6)0, (1+6)1, (2+6)2, (3+6)3, ..., (n+6)n

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple way to solve such a problem: You notice that not the terms, but the increments are in arithmetic progression. I hope you also know that when the increment is linearly increasing, then by integration, the expression will be a quadratic equation. What you can do now is: Assume a quadratic equation of the form "ax^2 + bx + c = k". Here, 'x' is the variable corresponding to the nth term of the sequence, and 'k' is the value of the nth term; now simply put n=1, 2 and 3 to obtain 3 linear equations in 'a', 'b' and 'c', which can be solved for their values. And there you have your general quadratic expression. (Pardon the crude script, it's been a while since I used LATEX. Any editing would be appreciated.)